# How does aud claim value set in ROPC access token

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, azure-active-directory

I am generating Authorization token to run our API tests using below method.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method returns the Bearer token with User as a claim
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tenantId">Tenant Id for the environment in use</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Email Id of the user</param>
    /// <param name="password">Password of the user</param>
    /// <returns>string with the complete Bearer token</returns>
    public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenROPC(string tenantId, string userName, string password)
    {
        string tokenUrl = string.Concat("https://login.microsoftonline.com/", tenantId, "/oauth2/v2.0/token");
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl)
        {
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["client_id"] = this.utils.GetClientId(),
                ["scope"] = "user.read openid profile email offline_access",
                ["client_secret"] = this.utils.GetClientSecret(),
                ["username"] = userName,
                ["password"] = password,
                ["grant_type"] = "password"
            })
        };
```

The response generates successfully and has access token with below claims.
My query is which part of code in above method takes care of aud claim and how does it is set https://graph.microsoft.com?:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/fa774de7-cc34-4a2d-838f-b83fdexxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1558960514,
  "nbf": 1558960514,
  "exp": 1558964414,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": 
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for user.read scope, which is the short form for `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`.

So you asked for a token to call MS Graph API. And you got a token to pass along in requests to there. 
You'd specify scopes for another API if you want an access token with a different audience.